# Is "indifferent of" correct in this sentence? Is it ever correct? Should I replace it with something?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

Is "indifferent of" correct in this sentence? Is it ever correct? Should I replace "of" with something?

> "In regards to hacking, do you approve, disapprove, or are you indifferent of the practice?"

Thank you.

Comment: "to" or "toward" ... the practice

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, but you should add **to**, **toward**, or **towards** before it. Also, you should replace **regards** with **regard**. While it's not technically incorrect (according to some; there is debate), it sounds more professional.

So the sentence should be:

> "In **regard** to hacking, do you approve, disapprove, or are you **indifferent to** the practice?"