# What is the meaning of the phrase "to your suffering"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I was [reading an article](https://www.wired.com/story/the-plan-to-put-a-3-d-printer-with-robot-arms-into-orbit/) on the internet and encountered a phrase like so:

> to your suffering

The full sentence is:

> Space is indifferent to your suffering.

I wonder what does "to your suffering" mean? It would be great if anyone can explain it.

Comment: It doesn't say "to your suffering" - it says "indifferent to your suffering". And it is explained in the immediately following sentence: it does not care if you suffer.

Comment: It helped me a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is 'be indifferent to' and can be followed by a noun or a gerund, so "Space is indifferent to your suffering." or "He is indifferent to your health." It means "not concerned by".

Comment: 'Indifferent to' has been [covered here before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234437/is-indifferent-of-correct-in-this-sentence-is-it-ever-correct-should-i-repla/234448#234448).